# Is the rise and dominance of analytic philosophy around the world associated with the dominance of the British empire and the United States?

Tags: philosophy, anglo-saxons

[Analytic Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy) largely originated from the Anglo-American tradition of philosophy. It is arguably the dominant type of philosophy practiced today in most major universities, *even in non English-speaking countries*.

What accounts for the popularity of analytical philosophy? For instance, do any of the leading scholars on this matter make the claim that this is historically related to (caused by) the dominance of the British Empire and the United States?

Comment: The first sentence of [its WikiPedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy) certainly seems to say so: "Analytic philosophy is a branch and tradition of philosophy using analysis which is popular in the Western World **and particularly the Anglosphere**, which began around the turn of the 20th century in the contemporary era and continues today."

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, but it doesn’t say whether the popularity of this philosophy style among *non-English* speaking countries is due to the rise of the British empire?

Comment: True. Perhaps that clarification should be edited into the question?

Comment: @T.E.D. Just did. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is analytic philosophy dominant in India and China (at least a fourth of the population of the world)? What about France, Germany and Europe as a whole? As far as I know, there is something called Continental philosophy. And South America and Africa. And the muslim world. Have you done a survey of journals (not only in English)?

Comment: Can any form of philosophy be said to be dominant, outside the very limited circle of people who consider themselves philosophers?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it not opinion based (asked about the views of "leading scholars on this matter,").and nominate it for reopening.

Comment: Analytic philosophy is viewed as having a certain amount of scientific rigor, especially when compared to Continental alternatives. Given the cultural dominance of science, it would be surprising if the type of philosophy which is most associated with science *wasn't* dominant.

Comment: You mention both "related to" and "caused by" US/British rule, which are very different things. I'm sure there are political considerations limiting the spread of Marxist philosophy in the US that would have benefited alternatives, and obviously philosophy written in English has a wider audience than in Romanian. But given that analytic philosophy only became popular in the mid 20th century, it's hard to see a direct link with the British empire. There are many histories of analytic philosophy in different times and places which you could consult: try e.g. Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.